# Filtering data in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I know WHERE, LIKE, IN filters in database. But how can I filter with "except" ? I want to select all data except a specificdata.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with NOT IN, usage is like IN

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ID NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Three approaches:

```
WHERE column <> 'something' 
WHERE column NOT LIKE 'something' 
WHERE column not in('something')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `NOT IN`

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can use another query for NOT IN like this:

```
SELECT id FROM customers WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM bad_customers)
```

Comment: Can I insert the values of an array in IN(values of an array)?

Answer (score 0):

WHERE NOT LIKE

WHERE NOT IN